# Organising C++ code

Tags: c++, layout, static

I am looking for some advice on how to organise my C++ code.

I have an int array, side, that I would like to be static in the sense that its value is kept constant between calls. This is because my function foo(), will modify the array side recursively and so I don't want copies to be made of side. Furthermore, the size of side can only be determined at compile time from the size of a vector that is passed into the function bar().

I have thought of the following structure to layout such a problem.

I keep a global int pointer, side, which I can then use to point to the address of my int array and then use the pointer *side within foo to do my modifications.

Please can you give me advise on the layout and organisation of this code? I am quite new to C++ so would appreciate any advice on the below structure.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int *side;

class A {
    public:
        int foo(bool);
        int bar(vector<int>);
        void set_n(int n){ class_n = n;};
    private:
        int class_n;
};

int A::foo(bool fl)
{
    int n = class_n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // modify side[] and then recursively call foo
    }

    return 0;
}

int A::bar(vector<int> t)
{
    int size = t.size();
    set_n(size);
    int a = foo(true);

    int *side_local = new int[size]; 
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        side_local[i] = 0;
    }
    side = side_local;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    vector<int> t = {1, 2, 3};
    a.bar(t);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why did you include `<vector>`, but failed to use it here: `int *side_local = new int[size]; `?  Why not simply `std::vector<int> side_local(size);`?  Or just simply `side.resize(size);` and not do any of that code?

Comment: It depends on the context, and you give none. What is the array supposed to represent ? Is it linked to A in some way ? Should it be owned by A ? Why not use a vector ? You won't be making copies by passing a reference or a pointer around...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive call can pass a pointer to itself:

```
void foo(int *pList)
{
    foo(pList); // recursive
}
```

the same list is then being worked on.

That being said, since foo is inside a class you wouldn't need a global either, but a member variable.

```
class A
{
    int *pMemberList;
    ...
    void foo();
}
```

now foo can see pMemberList all the time.

BUT ... passing it is probably a better option as in the future your class might house 2 lists that you want to do `foo` on.